# Middleman gives 404 in Article Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404, middleman

I'm getting started building out a blog with Middleman using the middleman-blog extension. Everything is working great so far on the home page. The problem occurs when I click on a link to see the full blog post. The full blog post page has no CSS being applied to it. After further inspection, I am receiving a 404 error. I fixed it on Dev Tools by moving 3 levels up in my CSS link href like so:

BEFORE (works in Home Page but not in Article pages)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/global.sass">
```

AFTER (moving two levels up no longer gives me a 404)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../stylesheets/global.sass">
```

My question is: What do I need to modify so that Article Pages look for the CSS 3 levels up while the home page remains intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the easiest way would be to use webroot-relative paths.

To recap, you're using a regular relative path...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/global.sass">
```

If your page is at `http://example.com/index.html`, then the browser will look for `http://example.com/stylesheets/global.sass`.

But if your page is at `http://example.com/blogs/2013/03/20/blogpost.html`, the browser will look for `http://example.com/blogs/2013/03/20/stylesheets/global.sass`

---

Now, the solution...

If you add a slash to the beginning of the path, you make that relative path into a webroot-relative path. The web browser will start looking for the file at the webroot...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/global.sass">
```

So, regardless of whether your page is at `http://example.com/index.html`, `http://example.com/blogs/2013/03/20/blogpost.html` or `http://example.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/page.html`, the browser will, in all cases, look for the file at `http://example.com/stylesheets/global.sass`.

---

The [Adobe Dreamweaver documentation on linking and navigation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c44a.html) explains this a bit more completely.

Comment: It's also possible to make [protocol-relative paths](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), which can help avoid "this page contains both secure and non-secure elements" warnings being shown to users.

Comment: That's exactly my problem and a perfect solution for it. Thank you so much!